# Add something to the method Security in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, annotations, twig

I have a code like that actually

**In Symfony controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/form/partners/{id}/{formState}", name="bodyshopPartnerEdit")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN') || has_role('ROLE_BODYSHOP_HANDLER_PARTNER_EDIT')")
 */
public function editPartner(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
```

**In Twig template**

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_BODYSHOP_HANDLER_PARTNER_EDIT') %}
```

I would like to know if I can modify the *has_role()* and *is_granted()* methods to automatically accept the **ROLE_ADMIN** instead of check two roles each times

Thank's !

Comment: check these: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/security.html
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html

look for inhereting or custom security voters

Comment: For `Twig` alone, you define your own function which does the same, but since you need that to be done in `@Security` as well, I would go for  @Themer's solution

Answer (score 4):

you can use Hierarchical Roles and test on the role "ROLE_BODYSHOP_HANDLER_PARTNER_EDIT"

```
security:
# ...

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_BODYSHOP_HANDLER_PARTNER_EDI]
```

In your controller :

```
 /**
  * @Route("/form/partners/{id}/{formState}",name="bodyshopPartnerEdit")
  * @Security("has_role('ROLE_BODYSHOP_HANDLER_PARTNER_EDIT')")
  */
 public function editPartner(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em){
     ...........
    }
```